# Selecting unequal columns from different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql and I have three tables T1, T2, T3
they contain data as follows:

```
+-------+
| t1.id |
+-------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
| 5    |
+------+

+-------+
| t2.id |
+-------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
+-------+

+-------+
| t3.id |
+-------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
+-------+

    I want to be able to select data as follows:

id      t1.id   t2.id   t3.id
1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2
3       3       3       3
4       4       4       null
5       5       null    null
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens to 5 from `t1.id`?

Comment: there is no gurantee that one of the tables will have greater number of rows than other. We can very well have 5 ids in T2 and only 3 in T1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.id=t3.id
```

works, if `t1` is guaranteed to have a strict superset of all ids.

If not, you would need a helper table:

```
SELECT th.id,t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
FROM (
  SELECT id FROM t1
  UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT id FROM t2
  UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT id FROM t3
) AS th
LEFT JOIN t1 ON th.id=t1.id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON th.id=t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON th.id=t3.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you intend to use `T1` as the base `id`, a pair of `LEFT JOIN`s will give you your desired result:

```
SELECT 
  /* base id */
  T1.id AS id,
  /* Redundant t1.id */
  T1.id AS t1_id,
  T2.id AS t2_id,
  T3.id AS t3_id
FROM
  T1
  LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
  LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.id = T3.id
```

Note that this makes redundant use of `T1.id`, but that's exactly what you have in your suggested output so I duplicated it here.

If what you really want is to take all possible ids from all tables, use a `UNION` to join against.  This will combine the distinct set of ids from the three tables into a subquery `allids` used as a base id to `LEFT JOIN` each of the other three tables against.  If a particular id exists in `T2` but *not* `T1` then, it will still appear in the output.

```
SELECT 
  allids.id AS id,
  T1.id AS t1_id,
  T2.id AS t2_id,
  T3.id AS t3_id
FROM
  ( SELECT id FROM T1 UNION SELECT id FROM T2 UNION SELECT id FROM T3 ORDER BY id) allids
  LEFT JOIN T1 ON allids.id = T1.id
  LEFT JOIN T2 ON allids.id = T2.id
  LEFT JOIN T3 ON allids.id = T3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you want involves full outer join:

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.id, t2.id, t3.id) as id,
       T1.id as t1_id, T2.id as t2_id, T3.id as t3_id
FROM T1 full outer JOIN
     T2 ON T2.id = T1.id full outer JOIN
     T3 ON T3.id = coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)
```

I propose the full outer join, in case there are ids in the other two tables that are not in T1.  You didn't specify that t1 is the driving table.